# Problem with Visual Studio WPF Designer! :(

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

Why i get this error:

```
'{DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}' is not a valid value for the 'System.Windows.Controls.Panel.Background' property on a Setter.
```

I'm sure that all controls styles, set well, But Visual Studio Designer display this error! :'( I'm sure that code is OK, and i don't want fill your browser screen with a lots of codes...

I saw this error many times, and i don't know how debug it! Please help me, If u khow some debug tips!

EDITED:

in Player.xaml(UserControl):

```
<Button Height="40" Name="btnNext"  Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=NextButton}" Click="btnNext_Click" />
```

After i Rebuild the project, i saw error on the line above #:-s

in Constants.xaml:

```
<ImageBrush x:Key="nextImage" ImageSource="../Images/next.png" />
```

in Generic.xaml:

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="NextButton">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=nextImage}" />
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=PlayerButtonTemplate}" />
    </Style>
```

Thanks in advance...:)

Comment: Cab you post the code that generates this error.

Comment: If you are using any customized or 3rd party controls, remove them all and see if that clears it up. If so, start adding them back until you isolate the one(s) that cause(s) problems.

Comment: no please do not fill up my browser screen with codes. i like my programming Q&A site to be free of code

Comment: @ChrisF: Error list window show nothing! :'(

Comment: What code do you have? There must be some XAML or C# that generates this error. Post the **minimum** code that repeats the problem.

Comment: Since this is certainly not the answer you're looking for i'll restrict myself to a comment: Just don't *ever* use the Visual Studio designer, it's junk.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Heh!

Finally I solve that! I just change every `StaticResource` to `DynamicResource`, and every thing is fine now!

Answer (score 2):

Change `StaticResource` to `DynamicResource`, but not for base controls.